# Add or Remove multiple records without manual comparision

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have three tables: `Person`, `Books` and `PersonBook`. `Person` and `Books` are the main tables and `PersonBook` is a "mapping table" between them.

The logic is very simple: Each person has multiple books. In the Add / Remove Book Screen, the Person can Add a new book or remove the existing book.

> Note: I depicted only the limited column for easy understanding, but
>   the actual table has large number of columns and much more constrains.

Person:

```
PersonId    FirstName    LastName
_____________________________________
1           Emma         Watsan
2           John         Peter
3           Albert       Einsten
(....)
```

Book:

```
BookId      BookName                ISBN           Author           
___________________________________________________________
1           Beautiful Darkness
2           Bones Never Lies
3           The Lion
(...)
```

PersonBook:

```
Id    PersonId     BookId
___________________________
1     1            1
2     2            3
3     3            3
(...)
```

I have a list `PersonBook`, and I need to update it in the table using Entity State.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
Context.PersonBook.RemoveRange(Context.PersonBook.Where(m => m.PersonId == PersonId));
Context.PersonBook.AddRange(ListOfBooks);
```

Here I give a simple condition:

```
Context.PersonBook.Where(m => m.PersonId == PersonId)
```

But in reality, I have many checks.

My Requirement is to remove only the records which do not exist in the local collection `ListOfBooks` and add the records which do not exist in the `DbSet`.

> Note: Each Person has 1K+ Books. In each edit request, comparing of
>   all the records leads to performance degradation and what I am doing
>   currently is better than that comparison, but it increases the
>   primary key (auto Incremental Key `PersonBook.Id`) value to very large numbers.

Comment: Out of topic answer: why didn't to use m-n EF feature? It creates and handle the Junction table for you...

Comment: @bubi - Could you please elaborate in Answers section please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison will be much faster if you prepare and use a fast lookup data structures. Since here you are processing the person books, it could be a `Dictionary<int, PersonBook>` for both old and new records with `BookId` being a key:

```
var oldBooks = Context.PersonBook.Where(e => e.PersonId == PersonId).ToDictionary(e => e.BookId);
var newBooks = ListOfBooks.ToDictionary(e => e.BookId);
Context.PersonBook.RemoveRange(oldBooks.Values.Where(e => !newBooks.ContainsKey(e.BookId)));
Context.PersonBook.AddRange(newBooks.Values.Where(e => !oldBooks.ContainsKey(e.BookId)));
```

Comment: Good solution, so is this only sensible to do if you have a lot of data or even with small sets?

Comment: Should be good for all cases. Building hash structure has O(n) complexity, so the resulting complexity is like O(n + m), while enumerable comparisons lead to O(m * n).

Comment: Why use `ToDictionary`? you could just `Select(x => x.BookId).ToArray()`

Comment: @Will In order to perform fast `ContainsKey` (which is the key point of the answer)

Comment: The problem is that the method isn't executed in code, it's converted to a query, so even if `ContainsKey` were faster than `Contains` or `Array.IndexOf`, it wouldn't matter because it's converted to `where [BookId] in (1,2,3,4,5,6...)` and executed in the db...

Comment: @Will Not sure what method do you have in mind. The first line executes db query and materializes the result in memory. The `RemoveRange` and `AddRange` do not execute queries at all, they just work with the context change tracker internal lists.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, use contains to see if something is in the list and then exclude it if it is:

```
Context.PersonBook.RemoveRange(
            Contect.PersonBook.where(m => m.PersonId == PersonId 
                                    && !ListOfBooks.Contains(m)));

Context.PersonBook.AddRange(ListOfBooks.Where(r => !Context.PersonBook.Contains(r))));
```

Comment: Yes I agree with your answer, but is there is any way to do using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @Mastero This method fulfills the requirement (not removing that what will be added and only add that which is not there). So I'm not exactly sure what you want different, also I'm not that familiar with EF so I honestly don't know about the attach etc.

Comment: Here we are doing one filter in our local collection (doing filter for both Add / Remove) and implicitly the Context is doing one filter before `Removing` or `Adding`. I will wait for an hour, if I got any better solution I take that otherwise I mark your answer as correct. (Obviously yours is correct.)

Comment: @Mastero Wish I understood the EF stuff haha (more of a linq 2 sql person myself). Hope you get the solution you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question but you could use the EF n-m relationships feature.
In your case the configuration should be

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany<Book>(user => user.OwnedBooks)
    .WithMany(book => book.Owners)
    .Map(mapping =>
    {
        mapping.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
        mapping.MapRightKey("BookId");
        mapping.ToTable("PersonBook");
    });
```

Using this configuration EF will create and handle the junction table (your PersonBook table) for you. If you enable automatic migration you will see that EF creates the table with 2 fields and a primary key on the 2 fields.

**EDIT**

Using these classes

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        OwnedBooks = new List<Book>();
    }

    [Column("PersonId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> OwnedBooks { get; set; }
}


public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        Owners = new List<Person>();
    }

    [Column("BookId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("BookName")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

with the above configuration (I think that you have to use fluent interface to configure m-n relationship) you obtain this model

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Books] (
 [BookId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [BookName] varchar(50) null
, [Isbn] varchar(50) null
, [Author] varchar(50) null
);
ALTER TABLE [Books] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Books_e63a83c6] PRIMARY KEY ([BookId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [People] (
 [PersonId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [FirstName] varchar(50) null
, [LastName] varchar(50) null
);
ALTER TABLE [People] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_People_e63a83c6] PRIMARY KEY ([PersonId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [PersonBook] (
 [PersonId] int not null
, [BookId] int not null
);
ALTER TABLE [PersonBook] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_PersonBook_e63a83c6] PRIMARY KEY ([PersonId], [BookId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_PersonId] ON [PersonBook] ([PersonId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_BookId] ON [PersonBook] ([BookId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [PersonBook] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonBook_People_PersonId] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonId]) REFERENCES [People] ([PersonId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [PersonBook] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonBook_Books_BookId] FOREIGN KEY ([BookId]) REFERENCES [Books] ([BookId])
```

Then I make some random insert/delete statements

```
Book book = new Book()
{
    Author = "Niccolò Ammaniti",
    Name = "Branchie"
};

book.Owners.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Mastero" });
book.Owners.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "bubi" });

context.Books.Add(book);
context.SaveChanges();
```

These are the queries that EF generates

```
ExecuteDbDataReader==========
insert into [Books]([BookName], [Isbn], [Author])
values (@p0, null, @p1);
select [BookId]
from [Books]
where [BookId] = @@identity
@p0 = Branchie
@p1 = Niccolò Ammaniti
ExecuteDbDataReader==========
insert into [People]([FirstName], [LastName])
values (@p0, null);
select [PersonId]
from [People]
where [PersonId] = @@identity
@p0 = Mastero
ExecuteDbDataReader==========
insert into [People]([FirstName], [LastName])
values (@p0, null);
select [PersonId]
from [People]
where [PersonId] = @@identity
@p0 = bubi
ExecuteNonQuery==========
insert into [PersonBook]([PersonId], [BookId])
values (@p0, @p1);

@p0 = 1
@p1 = 1
ExecuteNonQuery==========
insert into [PersonBook]([PersonId], [BookId])
values (@p0, @p1);

@p0 = 2
@p1 = 1
```

Then update/delete (from Junction table but for us is transparent)

```
book = new Book()
{
    Author = "Niccolò Ammaniti",
    Name = "Come Dio comanda"
};

Person person = context.People.Single(_ => _.FirstName == "bubi");
person.OwnedBooks.Add(book);

context.SaveChanges();

book.Owners.Remove(person);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And these are the queries

```
ExecuteDbDataReader==========
SELECT TOP 2 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [People] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 'bubi' = [Extent1].[FirstName]
ExecuteDbDataReader==========
insert into [Books]([BookName], [Isbn], [Author])
values (@p0, null, @p1);
select [BookId]
from [Books]
where [BookId] = @@identity
@p0 = Come Dio comanda
@p1 = Niccolò Ammaniti
ExecuteNonQuery==========
insert into [PersonBook]([PersonId], [BookId])
values (@p0, @p1);

@p0 = 2
@p1 = 2
ExecuteNonQuery==========
delete from [PersonBook]
where (([PersonId] = @p0) and ([BookId] = @p1))
@p0 = 2
@p1 = 2
```

You can download this code (and other insteresting configurations) from here

https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider/tree/master/JetEntityFrameworkProvider.Test/Model60_StackOverflow_m2n_Person_Book

They are tests for the Microsoft Access (Jet) Entity Framework provider but is very simple to adapt them for SQL Server.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to do the UPSERT process using this configuration.

Comment: You don't have upsert concept in this case. You have insert or delete. You obtain it working on user.OwnedBooks collection (adding and removing books then saving changes) and book.Owners (adding and removing owners then saving changes).